# decode php file help

Tags: php, decode

I had a file uploaded to my server called t.php in a directory called LANG

Can anyone decode this please, looks like it auto builds pages ..

(removed potentially malicious code; see the revision history)

Comment: 99% sure: Your server got pwned.

Comment: Looks like your server has been compromised. Check the permissions of the LANG folder to make sure it's not writable by just anyone. In terms of de-coding the uploaded script, it's just a waste of time (IMHO). Also, check your command history and logs to be sure that this is the only file that they left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main text blobs come out to:

```
$x0b = "file_get_contents";
$x0c = "header";

$source = "http://www.megavideo.com/xml/videolink.php?v=$vid"

echo "<h2>There was a problem parsing your XML</h2>"

$x0c("Location: http://www.megavideo.com/previewplayer/?v=&width=640&height=480")
```

So yes, you've been compromised. There's no legitimate reason to obfuscate `file_get_contents()` calls, particularly when pointing at a video sharing site.

Answer (score 0):

Those look like unix shellcodes. As to why they are uploaded as such, how did you upload them? FTP GUI client or command line tool or how?